# DataIntegrityViolationException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am trying to execute the following:

```
jdbcTemplate.update("DELETE FROM my_table WHERE created <= (NOW() - interval '? milliseconds')", 1);
```

but getting the following error:

org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [DELETE FROM my_table WHERE created <= (NOW() - interval '? milliseconds')]; The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.

I think it may be because the `?` is inside a string literal:

```
'? milliseconds'
```

but I'm not sure what the solution is?

I can execute the following ok using the SQL editor, and get results back:

```
select * from my_table where created <= (NOW() - interval '1 milliseconds');
```

Comment: This this one: (interval '1 milliseconds' * CAST(? AS INT) )